# Spark 1.2: Write single record into multiple files (blacklisted)

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I try to write multiple files (one per blacklist and grouped by a key) for each record in the RDD to HDFS, with a blacklist applied on each file set.

First i used **MultipleTextOutputFormat** in combination with **keyBy** to group the output files by a field in the record, which works fine. So my output files are now named by a key, from the records and the records are grouped in this files.

But my problem now is that, i need to apply blacklists on the output and save each of these outputs separately. I did this using a simple filter. What happens now is that applying this filer causes the job to be done X-times, for x different blacklists. For a huge number of records this is not acceptable. Even when call the cache function on the Dataframe before.

To make clear what i want my Input is one huge distributed HDFS file with the structure:

```
ID, Name, .
```

And my output directory should look like:

```
blacklisted1/ID1.file -> Content:(ID, Name, ...)
          /ID2.file
blacklisted2/ID1.file
          /ID2.file
```

The goal is to read each record only one time and write these file sets for it. My current approach is to use **forEachPartition** and the create a Files in HDFS manually by iterating though the records, but for me it looks like there must be a simpler solution for this.

Comment: Are the blacklists mutually exlusive? (ie. will each key show up in only one blacklist?)

Comment: no, every key could be contained in every blacklist.

Answer (score 1):

Since your keys aren't guaranteed to be in one blacklist, what I would do is generate a flatMap where you change your (key, value) RDD to (blacklist-key, value) where the data is potentially duplicated and then use the MultipleTextOutputFormat to write to file paths based on "blacklist/key". Something similar to this:

```scala
// Simple MultipleTextOutputFormat to output filename by key
// Directory separators are handled gracefully
class BlacklistMultipleTextOutputFormat extends MultipleTextOutputFormat[Any, Any] {
  override def generateActualKey(key: Any, value: Any): Any = NullWritable.get()

  override def generateFileNameForKeyValue(key: Any, value: Any, name: String): String = key.asInstanceOf[String]
}

myKvRdd = ... // your code to generate your RDD of (key, value)
blacklist:Map[String, Set[String]] = ... // your code to generate (key -> Set[Blacklist]) 

// Change it to (blacklist/key, value) where there is one row per key per blacklist that it blongs to
blacklisted = myKvRdd.flatMap(kv => blacklist.get(kv._1).map(b => (b + '/' + kv._1, kv._2)

// 100 partitions is pretty arbitrary, but it should be sufficiently large so that you don't OOM your executors
blacklisted.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(100))
    .saveAsHadoopFile("absoluteOutputPath", classOf[String], classOf[String],
        classOf[BlacklistMultipleTextOutputFormat])
```

Then you can generate your output in one pass of the RDD. Granted this RDD would be larger than the original one this workflow seems to fit better into spark's optimizations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will try it and post the results

Comment: The flatMap function would not generate multiple enties for each blacklist. But with your answer i finally found a solution. Using blacklist.keySet.map does the job.
Sadly it performs very bad, even slower then running a single job for each blacklist.

Comment: `blacklisted = myKvRdd.flatMap(kv => blacklist.keySet.get(kv._1).map(b => (b + '/' + kv._1, kv._2)`
This approach also blows up the temp directory from spark to Terrabytes.